# Idris Dependent Pairs: Unexpected behavior between compiled program and REPL

Tags: idris, dependent-type

When practicing using dependent pairs in Idris, I have encountered an unexpected difference in behavior between compiled programs and the REPL. The following datatype is what I am testing with:

```
(a : Type ** b : Type ** Arrow a b)
```

Which should represent some relation between type `a` and type `b`. Given an instance of the above, I would like to extract the "proof" term of the type. I can do this from the REPL with `DPair.snd $ DPair.snd <some-instance>` and everything works fine. However, if I try to make a function:

```
unwrap : (a ** b ** Arrow a b) -> Arrow a b
unwrap x = DPair.snd $ DPair.snd x
```

the program will compile, but will fail when I try to call it. The error message returned is

```
(input): No such variable b
```

Has anyone encountered this or knows of a solution?

Answer (score 0):

What you want to achieve is not possible. If you look at the type of `unwrap : (a1 : Type ** b1 : Type ** Arrow a b) -> Arrow a b` you see that it uses a different datatype than `(a : Type ** b : Type ** Arrow a b)`. That's because the arguments `a`, `b` are quantified beforehand - setting the resulting type (which is also the difference to the REPL case; there you aren't bound to the arguments). So with `:set showimplicit` it is

```
Main.unwrap : {b : Type} -> {a : Type} ->
              (a1 : Type ** b1 : Type ** Main.Arrow a b) ->
              Main.Arrow a b
```

That's the thing about dependent pairs, you can't restrict them easily. Take a look at `Vect.filter : (elem -> Bool) -> Vect len elem -> (p : Nat ** Vect p elem)` - if we had a function like `unwrap : (p : Nat ** Vect p elem) -> Vect p elem`, we wouldn't need dependent pair in the first place.

Instead, a function that would call `unwrap` would need to inspect `p` and then handle the `Vect` accordingly. Sadly, we can't easily inspect types (at least if you want to generalize for all types). So your best bet is: don't use dependent types here.

Answer (score 0):

I realise I'm a year and a half late, but... This absolutely is possible! You just need to remember that the type `a ** P` is just syntactic sugar for `DPair a (\x => P a)`; in the latter form, nothing special is going on whatsoever and so you can use your `a` and `b` just like you'd expect. We can also gain insight from how `DPair.snd` is typed in the standard library:

```
Idris> :t DPair.snd
snd : (x : DPair a P) -> P (fst x)
```

So, to extract the `a`-value from our pair, we simply call `fst` on that pair. How intuitive! (`fst` itself simply has the type `DPair a P -> a`). To get the `b`-value, which is the first value of the second part of our pair, we call `fst . snd` on the outermost pair. Therefore, your function should look like:

```
unwrap : (x : DPair a (DPair b . Arrow)) -> Arrow (fst x) (snd $ fst x)
unwrap x = snd (snd x)
```

(or, equivalently:)

```
unwrap : (x : DPair a (\theA => DPair b (\theB => Arrow theA theB))) -> ...
```

For whatever reason, `unwrap = DPair.snd . DPair.snd` doesn't work... but that's not too much of an issue.